# trim(str_replace) - can't understand why this is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter's Word_limiter function to get the initial few words of a string, and then another function to echo the rest of the string if needed.
However, I can't understand why this code won't work:

```
$full_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquam, ipsum sed porttitor fermentum, purus nisi semper leo, vel consectetur tortor lacus nec justo.";
$ellipsis = "<span id='ellipsis{$row['entry_id']}'> (more...)</span>"; 
$initial_text = word_limiter($full_text, 5, $ellipsis);
$additional_text = trim(str_replace($initial_text, '', $full_text));

echo $initial text; // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, (more...) [correct]
echo $additional_text; // This returns the entire string (full_text) with ellipsis in the middle
```

any ideas?

Comment: Explore your `word_limiter` function

Comment: Without knowing what the value of `$initial_text` is we really can't help you that much.

Comment: got it. how stupid, I was trying to find a string (which contained an additional ellipsis) in a full_text which didn't have the ellipsis. No wonder I couldn't match it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipsis part is added to `$initial_text`.  Therefore the `str_replace` finds nothing to replace since the entirety of `$initial_text` does not exist in `$full_text`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had just spotted it myself when I saw your comment. Funny how sometimes you think about it for half an hour, give up, ask on the forum, and as soon as you do it you get to the answer by yourself.

Comment: That being said, I would imagine it would be pretty trivial to modify `word_limiter()` function (or use a function which invokes it) to return both the desired shortened string (with ellipsis text) along with the remainder.